# NSTextField doesn't show when I set AttributedString placeholder

Tags: objective-c, macos, customization, nstextfield, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to customize a little bit my `NSTextFields` and the first step is to customize the `placeholder`.

I want to change the placeholder color, and I'm trying it out by this way:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    // Color for placeholder in NSTextField - Color: #cdc9c1
    NSColor *placeholderColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.80f green:0.78f blue:0.75f alpha:1.0f];

    NSDictionary *placeholderAttributeDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:placeholderColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

    NSAttributedString *emailPlaceholderString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Email" attributes:placeholderAttributeDict];
    // NSAttributedString *passPlaceholderString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Password" attributes:placeholderAttributeDict];

   // NSTextField Email attributes
   [[self emailTextField] setDrawsBackground:NO];
   [[self emailTextField] setBordered:NO];
   [[[self emailTextField] cell] setPlaceholderAttributedString:emailPlaceholderString];

   // NSTextField Password attributes
   [[self passTextField] setDrawsBackground:NO];
   [[self passTextField] setBordered:NO];
   [[[self emailTextField] cell] setPlaceholderString:@"Password"];
}
```

As you may see, the first placeholder in the first `NSTextField` is established by an `NSAttributedString` where i try to specify color. The second placeholder in the second `NSTextField` is just a `NSString`.

When i run the application, it only shows the second `NSTextField`. First one doesn't appear anywhere.

What is happening?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the same emailTextField twice...

```
[[[self emailTextField] cell] setPlaceholderAttributedString:emailPlaceholderString];

[[[self emailTextField] cell] setPlaceholderString:@"Password"];
```

(Does that fix things or was it just an error in the question?)